# How to use more than two custom emoji on a awaiting reaction?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So far I have this code but it’s only for two reactions and I want to know if someone can help me do more than two reactions? A custom emoji most preferably I will really appreciate the help.

```
const customEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('707879839943753758');

message.react(customEmoji).then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.id === customEmoji.id) {
            message.reply('report something');
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('did not report anything');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you not just continue doing `.then(() => message.react(emoji))` ? And then add more if statements in the `awaitReactions.then`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nameofemoji:idofemoji in [message.react()](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#custom-emojis)

You can get [id](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#unicode-emojis) emoji type `\:youremoji:` if `custom emoji`

```js
const emo0 = (':nameofemoji:idofemoji')
const emo1 = (':nameofemoji:idofemoji')

message.react(`${emo0}`)
.then(() => message.react(''))
.then(() => message.react(`${emo1}`))
.catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));
```